# Geoprocessing tools will not execute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing

When I try to execute geoprocessing tools (slope, viewshed...) I don't get any results. When I open the results window I see an hourglass icon like in the picture attached near the process. 
I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1

[image: Results]

Comment: Have you clicked the + for more info?

Comment: Yes. it's empty.

Comment: Is it empty or does it have ERROR 999999?

Comment: Has this ever worked? Have you rebooted?